# Hide content for small and extra small screen size devices

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, less

I need to hide some `HTML` contents from the screen when the devices are changing. That mean I am trying to create a responsive design. In small screen sizes (below 768px) I want to hide some contents.

My contents something like this -

```
<div class="content-to-hide">
   <div class="container">
        <a class="banner-brand visible-sm visible-md visible-lg" href="index.html">
           <img src=""  alt="" width="280">
        </a>
        <div class="utility-nav">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#"  id="example" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="left" title=""><i class="icon fa fa-users fa-lg"></i><br /><span>xxxxxxxxxxxxxx</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="#" title="View Cart"><i class="icon fa fa-unlock-alt fa-lg"></i><br /><span>Sign in</span></a></li>
             </ul>
             <h2><i class="icon fa fa-phone-square"></i> <span>Hot Line</span>xxx-xxx-xx-xx</h2>
         </div><!-- /.utility-nav -->

    </div><!-- /.container -->
    <div class="hr"><hr /></div>

</div>
```

So I want to hide this contents from small and extra small size screen devises.

I tried it using `LESSCSS` but no luck

```
@media (max-width: (@grid-float-breakpoint - 1)) {                  
   .content-to-hide {
      display: none;
   }
}
```

Hope someone will help my out.

Thank You.

Comment: with php.. get the screen's width and height, and depending on the results, do or do not echo that html-content into existence

Comment: Use Bootstrap's [`Responsive utilities`](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities)

Comment: Isn't this exactly what .hidden-xs does?

Answer (score 33):

why not use

```
@media (max-width: 767px) {                  
   .content-to-hide {
      display: none;
   }
}
```

if you want to hide the content for screen-size below 768px

Comment: ahh, thank you thank you! exactly what i was looking for!

Answer (score 3):

I'd go with Kyojimaru's response. Another option could be to use layout selectors. For example.

```
@media (orientation:portrait) {
   .my-element {
      display: none; /* visibility: none; */
   }
}
@media (orientation:landscape) and (max-width: 767px) {
   .my-element {
      display: none; /* visibility: none; */
   }
}
```