# How to create a logo image that spans 3 vertical div elements

Tags: html, css, layout, bootstrap-4

[image]

How to create a layout that allows having a logo image(yellow) that spans 3 vertical div elements and does not change its location(center) when the page gets minimized. I'm using Bootstrap 4. Initially, I have found 2 solutions but they do not work when the page is resized by minimizing its size.

1. Using CSS style **position: absolute** and **topY**/**offset** - does not work because logo image(yellow) change its position..**gray** div goes under the **pink** div as a result the logo image overlaps the **gray's** div text content
2. Splitting the logo image horizontally into 3 images, the problem is that between the second(middle) image and the bottom image appears a lot of space when minimizing the page

**NOTE**: when the page gets minimized, the **gray** div goes under the **pink** div, and the **green** div goes under the **gray** div, as a result, the second row becomes twice taller. No problem that it is twice taller, but I want that the logo(yellow) to stay vertically centered in its original **pink** div

Answer (score 1):

Place the 3 divs inside a wrapper

```
    <style>
        .wrapper{
        background-image:url("image.jpg");
        background-size:cover;
        }
   </style>  
  
  <div class="wrapper">
    // three divs go here
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is possible through `margin: negativevalue 0` -- but without actual code I can't give exact values. If standard Bootstrap 4, adding the class `my-n5` (taking advantage of [Bootstrap 4's spacing utility](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/spacing/)) to the logo element will make its box-model overlap others.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `position: absolute`, `top: 50%` and `transform: translateY(-50%)` to the logo to make it work

First, the `position: absolute` and `top: 50%` will make the logo position fixed in it's relative parent and make the top of the logo itself positioned in the center it's parent

Then the `transform: translateY(-50%)` will move the logo from the current position negatively for half of the logo height

Here's the working example

```css
.c1 {
  background: pink;
  overflow: visible;
}
.c2 {
  background: gray;
}
.c3 {
  background: lightblue;
}
.logo {
  width: 48px;
  height: 48px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  z-index: 100;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class='container-fluid'>
  <div class='row'>
    <div class='col-md-12'>
      1 DIV
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='row'>
    <div class='col-md-4 c1'>
      Left Content Logo
      <img class='logo' src='https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/d1/ShareX_Logo.png' />
    </div>
    <div class='col-md-3 c2'>
      Mid Content
    </div>
    <div class='col-md-5 c3'>
      Right Content
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='row'>
    <div class='col-md-3' style='background: blue;'>
      LEFT
    </div>
    <div class='col-md-6'>
      MID
    </div>
    <div class='col-md-3'>
      RIGHT
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Note**: You can try to resize either the `div` or the `logo` to see that it will still centered in it's relative parent container

Comment: It was used exactly the same solution(position: absolute, top: 50% and transform: translateY(-50%) and z-index) with exactly the same result :). As a result when the page gets  minimized the content of c2 "Mid Content" goes under the logo image. One solution can be  using jQuery(like ResizeSensor) and  increasing the height of c2(gray) or the height of c1(pink)

Comment: Decided temporary to hide the logo when the width becomes smaller than 900px, have found a solution in your comment https://stackoverflow.com/a/23946351/502332

Comment: @Igor sorry if it's the same results, because your notes says `No problem that it is twice taller, but I want that the logo(yellow) to stay vertically centered in its original pink div`. If your layout must stay the same in all device width, I think it's not possible using bootstrap, because there's media query used in bootstrap that will change the layout from column 4/12 (33.33%width) to 100%width when it hit certain width, which moves the c2 column below c1 column

Comment: It's either you keep your layout the same like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dMV2M.png) by setting the `meta viewport` tag in the `HTML` or set the minimum width of the `body` in the `CSS` or design a new layout for the Logo in mobile view or add some extra `padding-top` to `c2` when the width becomes smaller than `900px` so that the logo won't overlap with the content rather than hiding the logo